# iPhone customization of how phone ringing for phone contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

We have a requirement like this. First of all this is not a AppStore application and this is a company specific app distributed through enterprise license. Requirement is below.

Use can put the the phone in silent mode. (through the standard way). So that user cannot hear anything when he's receiving a call from somebody. But we have to be able to customize this (Through our application) for some contacts that, even though the phone is in silent mode, he can hear the ringing tone for incoming calls.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, at least not documented, you will need to search for undocumented api sources
Some sources are

- https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers
- http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z
- https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks
- http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/11/forbidden-fruit-apple-apis/

Maybe this is not the answer you are looking for, but searching in those sources may help you